# Searching by keyword in sqlite3 and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to search in my db by a keyword in sqlite3. But I am not able to do this. After creating the connection and cursor I use this line to try and get the columns I am looking for:
`curs.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE column1 LIKE {key_word}""").fetchall()`.
But when doing this I get the error:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: test3`.
Where test3 is the keyword I used here. I don't understand this error since I want to search the column: "column1".
Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. SELECT returns rows, not columns. What exactly do you try to SELECT? Can you give a concrete example with a Table and what exactly you want to get from it?

Comment: See the linked duplicates for how to do this correctly and securely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not clear what you are trying to do. In particular your usage of LIKE with a simple keyword.
But from a syntax point of view, you are missing some quotes (and probably some `%`, but that is up to you) around "test3".

```py
curs.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE column1 LIKE '{key_word}'""").fetchall()
```